# In Spacy pattern matching, how do we get bounded Kleene operator?

Tags: nlp, pattern-matching, spacy

In Spacy pattern matching, I know that we can use Kleene operator for ranges. For example,
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"},{ "OP": "*"}]. Here the star, known as kleene operator, means match against zero or any number of tokens. How can I modify the rule such that only 4 or 5 tokens are matched after the token "hello"?

In other NLP applications, for example,in GATE application, we can use some pattern like {Token.string == "hello"}({Token})[4,5] for the above task. Does Spacy have any such mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported, see the feature request: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5603.

In v3.0.6+, you can use the new `match_alignments` to filter matches in post-processing: https://spacy.io/api/matcher. The matcher will still be slow if your patterns with just `*` end up with a lot of long/overlapping matches.

Comment: Thanks @aab for directing me to the right direction. Appreciate.